# PHP convert diacritics does not work as expected

Tags: php, encoding

I need some help removing diacretics.

I have the following `Ä` character encoded in `UTF-8` and I want to remove the two dots:
`Ä -> A`

But I also want to have this for all existing characters (or the most) like this:

```
Ä => A    È => E    Ö -> O    Ü -> U
À => A    Ê => E    Ô -> O    Û -> U
Â => A    É => E    Ò -> O    Ù -> U    ...
```

I also found the function `Normalizer::normalize` but applying this on `Ä` still returns the same: `Ä`.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I keep this function in my back pocket for such occasions:

```php
<?php

function replaceAccents(string $str): string
{
    $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
    $str = preg_replace('/&([a-zA-Z])(uml|acute|grave|circ|tilde|ring);/', '$1', $str);
    return html_entity_decode($str);
}

$input = 'ÄÈÖÜÀÊÔÛÂÉÒÙ';
$output = replaceAccents($input);


echo $output.PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
AEOUAEOUAEOU
```

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but it's effective.